# Start a new UIViewController from a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, nib

I have a `UINavigationController` and I want to start from that navigation a new `UIViewController` that has its own view controller .
when I tried to do that , I faced this exception

> Could not load NIB in bundle loaded)' with name and directory 'Main.storyboardc''

I am adding the new view controller with these two line of code

```
            UIViewController *mainViewController =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CGMainViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:mainViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Is there any way to start a new `UIViewController` from a navigation controller without adding it to that navigation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Solved

my code is running correctly

> The `exception` appears because of a typing mistake of the identifier for the new view controller in the `storyboard`

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
[self presentViewController:newViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To modally present a new `UIViewController` without adding it to the `UINavigationController` stack

Also, If you want the new VC to be in a new `UINavigationController`, then:

```
UINavigationController * nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newViewController];
[self presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I can give more information if you are more clear in your question and present some code that you are getting the error from.

Comment: the above  exception appears when I doing that

Comment: How do you create and initialize `newViewController` in your code?